# Pc reboots after windows hardware evaluation

Tags: windows-7

Well, I built a PC from scratch, everything seems to work fine but I have a little problem, every time I try to do the windows evaluation theres a point who eventually restarts, I have looked in the event viewer and appears a critical event "kernel-failure" entry, I think it could be an issue with the power supply.

### Event:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<ViewerConfig>
-<QueryConfig>
-<QueryParams>
-<Simple>
<Source>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power</Source>
<Channel>System</Channel>
<Level>1</Level>
<EventId>41</EventId>
</Simple>
</QueryParams>
-<QueryNode>
<Name>Eventos de la página de resumen</Name>
-<QueryList>
-<Query Path="System" Id="0">
<Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power'] and (Level=1) and (EventID=41)]]</Select>
</Query>
</QueryList>
</QueryNode>
</QueryConfig>
</ViewerConfig>
```

### Event details:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>2</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-06T12:04:02.276804900Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1507</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DaGaMe-PC</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: Do you experience a Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) before the computer restarts?

Comment: No, black screen and reboots.

Comment: Could you use [WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) and let us know what you find? I think [this link](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed_resets) might be of particular interest to you.

Comment: check all 5 steps from scenario 3: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/en-us

Answer (score 0):

`Source: Kernel-Power Event-ID: 41` can have multiple causes, including driver problems but also overheating.

To see if its a problem with overheating you may stress your CPU. If nothing happens, stress the graphics adapter. But when the error occures after high loading the graphics adapter, it can also be a driver problem.